# Understanding an example of a discrete valuation ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, extension-field

[image]

I can understand the (little) reasoning to the point of supposing that $x$ belongs in the discrete valuation ring. Assuming that $\mathfrak{p}$ is the (to be proven) maximal ideal, I don't understand what's the reasoning there. 
Could anyone point out what I'm missing here? 
Thanks in advance!

Edit: I should mention two things.

1. The example can be found in "Introduction to Algebraic and Abelian Functions" by S. Lang.
2. I'm open to different proofs of the given statement.

Comment: What is the exact reasoning you don't understand?

Comment: I don't understand why $\mathfrak{p} \cap k[x]$ must be generated by an irreducible polynomial of degree 1.

Comment: Because that intersection lives in $k[x]$ which is a principal ideal domain, it is generated by a single polynomial. Since the ideal is prime, the polynomial has to be irreducible. Since $k$ is algebraically closed, the polynomial has to be of degree $1$ otherwise it will be a polynomial with no roots in $k$, contradiction.